# Metal alphaBlendOperation .max weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, draw, metal

I'm using metal to draw some lines, my drawing canvas has a texture in `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` and when I draw inside it blending is enabled `MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor` and I'm using `alphaBlendOperation = .max`

```
    renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    let attachment = renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0]
    attachment?.texture = self.texture
    attachment?.loadAction = .load
    attachment?.storeAction = .store


    let rpd = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    rpd.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .rgba8Unorm 
    let attachment = rpd.colorAttachments[0]!
    attachment.isBlendingEnabled = true
    attachment.rgbBlendOperation = .max
    attachment.alphaBlendOperation = .max
```

I can change the properties in brush (size, opacity, hardness "blur"). However first two brushes are working really great as in the image bellow

[image: ![Normal brush drawing]

**But I have only one weird behavior when I use blurred brush with faded sides where lines are connected the faded areas is not blending as expected and an empty small line created between the connection. the image bellow described this issue, please check the single line and single point and then check the connections you can see this behavior very clear**

[image: ![![Drawing with blurred brush]

MTLRenderPassDescriptor Should choose even the bellow alpha from down texture or brush alpha but when tap in the second and third point its making empty line instead of choosing a one of the alpha, Its like making alpha zero in these areas.

This is my faded brush you can see there is a gradian of color but i don't know if there is a problem with it

[image]

Please share with me any idea you have to solve it